# Add multiple FilePaths from OpenFileDialog to List<>

Tags: c#, .net, path, openfiledialog

I'm currently trying to add all the filePaths of the pictures that I selected through an OpenFileDialog to a List<>. However, when I try to start the program only the path of the first file is added to the List multiple times.

This is the code I tried with

```
            OpenFileDialog MyDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            MyDialog.Filter = "Picture (.jpg)|*jpg|Picture (.jpeg)|*.jpeg|Picture (.png)|*.png";
            MyDialog.Multiselect = true;
            if (MyDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                foreach (String file in MyDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    string fullPath = MyDialog.FileName;
                    FileListe.Add(Convert.ToString(new BitmapImage(new Uri(fullPath))));
                }

            }
```

Comment: Use:                    string fullPath = file;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do it like this. you are using `MyDialog.FileName` instead of that you should use `file`

```
FileListe.Add(Convert.ToString(new BitmapImage(new Uri(file ))));
```